# How can I uninstall fuse-ext2 and macfuse on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, uninstall, macfuse

Can you please tell me how can I uninstall fuse-ext2 and MacFUSE on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 13):

From the [MacFUSE FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/wiki/FAQ#2._Install/Uninstall_Questions):

**How can I uninstall MacFUSE?**

Launch the Mac OS X System Preferences application and go to the MacFUSE preference pane. Click on the "Remove MacFUSE" button. This will uninstall all MacFUSE components except the preference pane itself.

You can keep the MacFUSE preference pane around should you decide to install MacFUSE again in the future. If you do wish to remove it, you do it just like how you would remove any other non-Apple preference pane: In System Preferences, control-click (right-click) on the MacFUSE icon and you will see "Remove ..." as an action.

**Only** if you had the "Show Beta Versions" button checked in the MacFUSE prefpane, you'll have a property list (plist) file remaining at this point: `/Library/Preferences/com.google.macfuse.plist`. To remove it, you should uncheck the button before you remove the prefpane as described above.

Note that an official (correct) MacFUSE installation will have a preference pane if you have MacFUSE 2.0 or later installed. If you have an older version of MacFUSE, you can uninstall as follows.

---

**Deprecated Installation Information**

Run the `uninstall-macfuse-core.sh` script that resides in the `Support` subdirectory of the MacFUSE file system bundle. The bundle itself resides in `/System/Library/Filesystems/` on Mac OS X 10.4.x and in `/Library/Filesystems/` on Mac OS X 10.5.x.

For example, to uninstall MacFUSE on Mac OS X 10.4.x, you would run the following command in the Terminal:

```
sudo /System/Library/Filesystems/fusefs.fs/Support/uninstall-macfuse-core.sh
```

To uninstall MacFUSE on Mac OS X 10.5.x and above, you would run:

```
sudo /Library/Filesystems/fusefs.fs/Support/uninstall-macfuse-core.sh
```

If the file system bundle in your MacFUSE installation doesn't have a Support subdirectory, that means you have an incredibly ancient version of MacFUSE. Please look for the uninstall script within the `fusefs.fs/` directory itself.

Answer (score 3):

in addition to uninstalling MacFUSE (or FUSE for OS X if you installed it), you should also uninstall fuse-ext2 because it's not automatically removed. To do this, type this in terminal:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
fuse-ext2.uninstall -u
```

Comment: Note that you may need to be root to remove all the files.

Answer (score 0):

I use [cleanApp](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/cleanapp.html) for this but it's not free!!! but it's good application for uninstalling every application or system preference you install on your macbook.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @hải-phong I found list of all files to be installed by fuse-ext2 in source files (file [fuse-ext2.uninstall.m](https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2/blob/539c6ef/fuse-ext2/fuse-ext2.uninstall.m#L39)):

```
    "/Library/Receipts/fuse-ext2.pkg",
    "/Library/Filesystems/fuse-ext2.fs",
    "/System/Library/Filesystems/fuse-ext2.fs",
    "/Library/PreferencePanes/fuse-ext2.prefPane",
    "/System/Library/PreferencePanes/fuse-ext2.prefPane",
    "/usr/local/bin/fuse-ext2",
    "/usr/local/bin/fuse-ext2.wait",
    "/usr/local/bin/fuse-ext2.probe",
    "/usr/local/bin/fuse-ext2.mke2fs",
    "/usr/local/bin/fuse-ext2.e2label",
    "/usr/local/bin/fuse-ext2.install",
    "/usr/local/bin/fuse-ext2.uninstall",
    "/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/fuse-ext2.pc",
    "/usr/local/share/man/man1/fuse-ext2.1",
```

Don't know, why it is done through obj-c, but now we can write simple bash script. I created [gist for this](https://gist.github.com/erakli/413e170fe7c27fbc669f0e89778a46da).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).